# Protected View embedded in Tab View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, segue

I'm working on an app that should be hidden behind login view.

So in general, I have a tab navigation controller which should hold pretty much the entire app and my logic is when the app loads, the initial View controller is the tab navigation controller, which shows its first View IF the user is logged in. If it's not logged in, they should see login/register page. Both login and register page work with Parse, they are ok and function well. They are presented Modally (using segues) on top of the first View in the Tab view controller.

The issue is that when I login (and I confirm that it works!) the login View controller is not dismissed in order to see the tab view controller and I think that I might have messed something up in the segues. The segue to present the login view if the user is not logged in is made from the protected view (not it's navigation controller, although i tested that too, doesn't work) to login view controller.

Also, the code in the protected page is like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToLoginView", sender: self)
}
```

Here's what my story board looks like:

[image]

So, the login segue is presented modally and here's my code for the login button.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = usernameTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text


    // Sends to Parse to see if user exists
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user != nil {

            // LOGIN Successful
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            print("User logged in")

        } else {

            // Display Failed Login Alert message with confirmation
            let failedLoginAttepmt = UIAlertController(
                title: "Ups!",
                message: "Something went wrong, try again...",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
            )
            let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK!",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
                { action in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }

            failedLoginAttepmt.addAction(confirmAction)
            self.presentViewController(failedLoginAttepmt, animated: true, completion: nil)

            print("Could not find the user")
        }
```

and this line of code `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` should dismiss the modally presented login view controller, as I do see the print statement in the console.

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I figured it out.

I forgot to add logic for checking if the user is actually logged in! If you don't have logic, the View controller will simply show you the login view controller over and over again.